# Querying IMAPITable for data during a search operation

Tags: c++, winapi, outlook, mapi

Similarly to my other previously opened threads, I'm trying to achieve a fast and efficient folder search. I've tried waiting for `fvnSearchCompleted` event which took forever to arrive and for `fvnTableModified` with `TABLE_ROW_ADDED` which has never arrived due to `IMsgStore`'s decision tree (more than 10K mails)

Is it possible to query the IMAPITable associated with the `search_folder` during the search operation(SetSearchCriteria) and until the `fvnSearchCompleted` event.

In case it's plausible, a simple `IMAPTable->QueryRow` call with an infinitive loop is enough for that? the table's order wont change during the search operation, and the cursor will correctly move to the next record?

**Edit** I've found out that SetSearchCriteria, moves table's cursor position, each time it inserts new records to the search table, is there a way to overcome this behavior for on-the-fly table query?

Comment: Do you display the search results to the end user or just want to get thee data back as quickly as possible?

Comment: as quickly as possible

Comment: You most likely interfere with the search operation (the programmer's version of a kid in a back seat continuously asking "are we there yet?"). Just wait for the search to complete and then do what you need to do.

Comment: And what would you say if i told you the other thing? print results to user end? It seems strange that receiving results in real time is almost impossible with the IMAPIX engine. as previously asked with Containers notification which send TABLE_CHANGED rather than TABLE_ROW_ADDED and so on

Comment: The user only sees a limited subset of results (30 or 40 rows?) Outlook never reprieves the whole set. I think in your case it would still be better to explicitly loop through all child folders and synchronously apply restriction rather than create a search folder and deal with all the asynchronous notifications that work great when presenting results to an end user but do no make much sense to use in a code that runs with no UI.

Comment: Search folders also make sense if you create them once in mailbox and then just use the existing folder from that moment on.

Comment: But even if outlook never retrieves more than 30 - 40 results in a search, it still does it asyncly

Comment: Of course. It makes perfect sense in an app where the search results are only displayed to the end user. I am not at all sure it makes any sense in your case.